# Selecting columns by list (and delete first line)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a script that fetches rows from a database.
One of the columns contains sample text:

```
"Technical task from package TRF_DATABASE_YU_869

30-APR-21 TRYSG_6079 TRF_DATABASE_YU_869 Finish_Error
30-APR-21 TRYSG_6082 TRF_DATABASE_YU_869 Finish_Error
30-APR-21 TRYSG_6084 TRF_DATABASE_YU_869 Finish_Error
30-APR-21 TRYSG_6087 TRF_DATABASE_YU_869 Finish_Error"
```

my script:

```
task_list = []
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql_as_string = sql_file.read()
cursor.execute(sql_as_string)

for row in cursor:
    task_list.append(row)
 
for row in task_list:
    col = row[4]
    print(col)
```

I am searching for a way to delete a row "Technical task from package TRF_DATABASE_YU_869" and apply np.array somewhere about:

```
an_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
second_and_third_column = an_array[:, 2]
```

but i have a problem  col = row[4]  - it is a tuple and so I cannot use an_array[:, 2].
I would like to get the final result:

```
TRF_DATABASE_YU_869
TRF_DATABASE_YU_869
TRF_DATABASE_YU_869
TRF_DATABASE_YU_869
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the first row, all you need to do is to iterate from element 1 instead of zero, i.e:

```
for i in range(1, len(cursor)):
    task_list.append(cursor[i])
```

This would append everything except for the first row. As for the other question you had, could you give a better example of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you seem to have your input (the sample text) as a string, you could always just manually parse the lines from there by using string.find() and string.split(), for example:

```
string = samplestring
stringarray = []
linestoSkip = 2    # Feed in how many lines you want to skip
line=0

while True:
    line += 1
    lineChange = string.find("\n") #finds index of linechange
    row = string[:lineChange]
    if line <= linestoSkip:
        stringarray.append(row.split()) #split() splits the string at all whitespaces

    string = string[linechange+1:] # Remove the row from string for next loop
    if lineChange == -1:
        break # If .find() can't find a matching string, it returns -1 => break
```

And as a result, stringarray should have the data formatted into a neat 2D list. From there you should be able to easily pull any of the data you want :)